# D7. Facebook Stream: show user's feed

Tags: social-network

I try to display authorised user's news feed:
I installed Facebook Stream module in Drupal 7. After facebook login module displays an error:

> FacebookApiException: User must specify a valid extended permission or
>   data permission in BaseFacebook->throwAPIException() (line 1325 of
>   Z:\home\devfb.kz\www\sites\all\modules\facebook_stream\facebook-php-sdk\src\base_facebook.php).

I can't understand why permissions which I specified in the module are invalid?
Permissions:

```
return '<fb:login-button '. drupal_attributes($attr) .' onclick="FB_Connect.login_onclick()" scope="read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access">'. $text .'</fb:login-button>';
```

Maybe I can do this with another module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understud: I'm use "read_stream" scope without additional submit in my FB App settings. To access user's news feed I must submit my App to review and only after approval I'll have ability to get access to this API feature.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, you don't need a specific module at all to do this. You can just have embed code generated and add that to the source code for the block/page you want to add it to. You can have embed code generated [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/). Be sure to select "Show Posts" if that's what you want.

**Edit**: I just re-read your question and see that you mean to do this for the authorized user... in this case my answer may not be helpful.